# Cannot get Serial working

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I've bought a module which should communicate via serial RX/TX. The module and code are described here: https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Weather_Station_with_Anemometer/Wind_vane/Rain_bucket_SKU:SEN0186.

I've hooked up everything as described (using an Arduino Nano instead of an Uno, but the rest is the same) and now trying to get things to work. I could not get any decent output. So I decided to switch to a bare-minimum program to read stuff from the serial port in order to see whats going on. I found the following sample: https://gist.github.com/Protoneer/96db95bfb87c3befe46e and implemented this code (only this).

Now what I see is the following: 
- With RX/TX connected **the wrong way**, when I reset the nano, the serial monitor shows me one instance of the string I'm looking for (as described in the module documentation). When connected the right way, the text is not there but that's to be expected as the nano should receive it (and not the serial monitor). This does however prove that the module is actually sending data. 
- `Serial.available` seems to evaluate to 0 all the time, indicating there is no data to be read from the serial line.

So why would `Serial.available` return 0 even though there seems to be data being sent to serial, as the monitor does show the string I'm looking for with the pins crossed. I have also tried disconnecting the RX line on the module to prevent statements being sent over serial to interfere with the module. The documentation does not state the need to send anything to the module in order to trigger the response. In fact, if you look at the sample code the first interaction with serial (after `Serial.begin(9600)`) is `Serial.available()`.

Is there anything else I can do from a debug perspective? As you might notice I'm no expert in this stuff.

Comment: 1st thought, Nano boards come in 3 and 5 volt versions.  The weather station clearly says it is a 5 volt device. Maybe you have the wrong Nano?

Comment: No voltage is correct, it's hooked to 5V on the nano.

Comment: If the serial terminal is showing you the data then it means you have the TX and RX pins connected the wrong way around.

Comment: @Majenko you're right, I was mixing up test results. With the cables connected the right way (RX-TX, TX-RX) I'm actually not getting the contents on the serial monitor. But the end result stays the same: Serial.available returns false and there's no data incoming, even though having the wires the other way around seems to indicate data is being sent.

Comment: `available()` returns count of available data.

Comment: Yeah the actual check is Serial.available() > 0 (which returns false).

Comment: so you copy data from Serial to Serial echoing them to the device in ascii form? what could be the reaction of the device?

Comment: See the gist, the sample code takes whats coming in and prints it, nothing more. But as there is no code coming in at all, there's no prints as well. 

If I do `Serial.println`, is that being sent to the device as well? I have no clue how it would respond to that.

Comment: is the RX of the device connected to TX of Nano? then Serial output of Nano is send to the device

Comment: Its connected yes, I tried disconnecting the TX from nano (so only TX module => RX nano connected)  but that gives the same result, available return 0.

Comment: @Jasper, there is a saying that the RS232 protocol (never mind the physical bit) is the standard that is not a standard. I would recommend you discover this your self by abandoning the embedded world and connect your weather "thing" to a computer with a configurable application such as RealTerm.  Once you figured out the proper configuration you can work your self back to the embedded world.

Comment: sorry about that 2400 baud. it is in the other weater station question

Comment: So, you have the module connected to the Nano pins 1 and 2, and are also trying to communicate with the PC via the `Serial` object and serial monitor? There is a USB/serial converter chip on the Nano that is likely conflicting with your module. You can try SoftwareSerial to get a bit-banged serial port for communicating with the module on some other pins.

Comment: @josecanuc if you post that as an answer, I can give you the points you deserve :)

Comment: how did SoftwareSerial help if you need only RX to connect to the device and you are not sending anything over USB to Uno

Comment: @Juraj, pin 0 and 1 are connected to the usb-serial chip with a resistor. The signals can be overridden by something else, but we don't know how strong the tx signal from the module is.

Comment: @Jot, if it works in manufactures example, it should be strong enough

Comment: I'm also not sure what the issue is. Maybe it's my cheap Chinese nano that's causing the problems. Any way, I know for sure that now it's connected to other pins and using SoftwareSerial, it all works the way it should. I have a "real" uno lying around as well, will give it a go on that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have the module connected to the Nano pins 0 and 1, and are also trying to communicate with the PC via the `Serial` object and serial monitor?

There is a USB/serial converter chip on the Nano that is likely conflicting with your module. You can try SoftwareSerial to get a bit-banged serial port for communicating with the module on some other pins.

Comment: you mean pins 0 and 1 - RX and TX?

Comment: Corrected answer to refer to RX/TX pins 0/1.

Comment: How is it conflicting? The device only sends data to RX of Nano. TX is not connected to the device so the Nano doesn't send data to the device, only to USB. Nothing is sent from computer to Nano and it would not stop the device.

Comment: @Juraj , well even if nothing is sent from the computer, the tx of the usb-serial chip is connected (with a resistor) to the rx of the atmega chip. josecanuc, for 9600 baud, I prefer the AltSoftSerial.

Comment: This indeed fixed it, SoftwareSerial on pins 10 and 11 works as expected.